# Invalid length of startup packet when connecting to docker postgres

Tags: python, postgresql, kubernetes, uwsgi

I have created an app using helm on `k8s` with `istio`.

It consists of 2 microservices, the front-end/api and the db (postgres).

The api uses a `uwsgi` service.

Upon start, it fails with the following error:

```
alerta-5d7db46658-jpdkm alerta Traceback (most recent call last):
alerta-5d7db46658-jpdkm alerta server closed the connection unexpectedly
alerta-5d7db46658-jpdkm alerta  This probably means the server terminated abno
rmally
alerta-5d7db46658-jpdkm alerta  before or while processing the request.
alerta-5d7db46658-jpdkm alerta
alerta-5d7db46658-jpdkm alerta
alerta-5d7db46658-jpdkm alerta 2020-05-03 13:31:43,360 DEBG 'uwsgi' stdout out
put:
alerta-5d7db46658-jpdkm alerta Traceback (most recent call last):
alerta-5d7db46658-jpdkm alerta   File "./wsgi.py", line 1, in <module>
alerta-5d7db46658-jpdkm alerta
alerta-5d7db46658-jpdkm alerta 2020-05-03 13:31:43,360 DEBG 'uwsgi' stdout output:
alerta-5d7db46658-jpdkm alerta     from alerta import app
alerta-5d7db46658-jpdkm alerta   File "/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/alerta/__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
alerta-5d7db46658-jpdkm alerta     app = create_app()
alerta-5d7db46658-jpdkm alerta   File "/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/alerta/app.py", line 67, in create_app
alerta-5d7db46658-jpdkm alerta     db.init_db(app)
alerta-5d7db46658-jpdkm alerta   File "/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/alerta/database/base.py", line 47, in init_db
alerta-5d7db46658-jpdkm alerta     self.create_engine(app, uri=app.config['DATABASE_URL'], dbname=app.config['DATABASE_NAME'])
alerta-5d7db46658-jpdkm alerta   File "/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/alerta/database/backends/postgres/base.py", line 64, in create_engine
alerta-5d7db46658-jpdkm alerta
alerta-5d7db46658-jpdkm alerta 2020-05-03 13:31:43,361 DEBG 'uwsgi' stdout output:
alerta-5d7db46658-jpdkm alerta     conn = self.connect()
alerta-5d7db46658-jpdkm alerta   File "/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/alerta/database/backends/postgres/base.py", line 104, in connect
alerta-5d7db46658-jpdkm alerta     raise RuntimeError('Database connect error. Failed to connect after {} retries.'.format(MAX_RETRIES))
alerta-5d7db46658-jpdkm alerta RuntimeError: Database connect error. Failed to connect after 5 retries.
alerta-5d7db46658-jpdkm alerta unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
alerta-5d7db46658-jpdkm alerta
alerta-5d7db46658-jpdkm alerta 2020-05-03 13:31:43,361 DEBG 'uwsgi' stdout output:
alerta-5d7db46658-jpdkm alerta mounting wsgi:app on /api
alerta-5d7db46658-jpdkm alerta
alerta-5d7db46658-jpdkm alerta 2020-05-03 13:31:43,365 DEBG 'uwsgi' stdout output:
alerta-5d7db46658-jpdkm alerta Traceback (most recent call last):
alerta-5d7db46658-jpdkm alerta   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/logging/config.py", line 388, in resolve
alerta-5d7db46658-jpdkm alerta
alerta-5d7db46658-jpdkm alerta 2020-05-03 13:31:43,365 DEBG 'uwsgi' stdout output:
alerta-5d7db46658-jpdkm alerta     found = getattr(found, frag)
alerta-5d7db46658-jpdkm alerta AttributeError: module 'alerta' has no attribute 'utils'
alerta-5d7db46658-jpdkm alerta
alerta-5d7db46658-jpdkm alerta During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
alerta-5d7db46658-jpdkm alerta
alerta-5d7db46658-jpdkm alerta Traceback (most recent call last):
alerta-5d7db46658-jpdkm alerta   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/logging/config.py", line 543, in configure
alerta-5d7db46658-jpdkm alerta
alerta-5d7db46658-jpdkm alerta 2020-05-03 13:31:43,365 DEBG 'uwsgi' stdout output:
alerta-5d7db46658-jpdkm alerta     formatters[name])
alerta-5d7db46658-jpdkm alerta   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/logging/config.py", line 654, in configure_formatter
alerta-5d7db46658-jpdkm alerta
alerta-5d7db46658-jpdkm alerta 2020-05-03 13:31:43,366 DEBG 'uwsgi' stdout output:
alerta-5d7db46658-jpdkm alerta     result = self.configure_custom(config)
alerta-5d7db46658-jpdkm alerta   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/logging/config.py", line 469, in configure_custom
alerta-5d7db46658-jpdkm alerta
alerta-5d7db46658-jpdkm alerta 2020-05-03 13:31:43,366 DEBG 'uwsgi' stdout output:
alerta-5d7db46658-jpdkm alerta     c = self.resolve(c)
alerta-5d7db46658-jpdkm alerta   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/logging/config.py", line 391, in resolve
alerta-5d7db46658-jpdkm alerta
alerta-5d7db46658-jpdkm alerta 2020-05-03 13:31:43,366 DEBG 'uwsgi' stdout output:
alerta-5d7db46658-jpdkm alerta     found = getattr(found, frag)
alerta-5d7db46658-jpdkm alerta AttributeError: module 'alerta' has no attribute 'utils'
alerta-5d7db46658-jpdkm alerta
alerta-5d7db46658-jpdkm alerta The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
alerta-5d7db46658-jpdkm alerta
alerta-5d7db46658-jpdkm alerta
alerta-5d7db46658-jpdkm alerta 2020-05-03 13:31:43,366 DEBG 'uwsgi' stdout output:
alerta-5d7db46658-jpdkm alerta Traceback (most recent call last):
alerta-5d7db46658-jpdkm alerta   File "./wsgi.py", line 1, in <module>
alerta-5d7db46658-jpdkm alerta     from alerta import app
alerta-5d7db46658-jpdkm alerta   File "/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/alerta/__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
alerta-5d7db46658-jpdkm alerta
alerta-5d7db46658-jpdkm alerta 2020-05-03 13:31:43,366 DEBG 'uwsgi' stdout output:
alerta-5d7db46658-jpdkm alerta     app = create_app()
alerta-5d7db46658-jpdkm alerta   File "/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/alerta/app.py", line 53, in create_app
alerta-5d7db46658-jpdkm alerta     logger.setup_logging(app)
alerta-5d7db46658-jpdkm alerta   File "/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/alerta/utils/logging.py", line 97, in setup_logging
alerta-5d7db46658-jpdkm alerta
alerta-5d7db46658-jpdkm alerta 2020-05-03 13:31:43,367 DEBG 'uwsgi' stdout output:
alerta-5d7db46658-jpdkm alerta     'handlers': app.config['LOG_HANDLERS']
alerta-5d7db46658-jpdkm alerta   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/logging/config.py", line 800, in dictConfig
alerta-5d7db46658-jpdkm alerta
alerta-5d7db46658-jpdkm alerta 2020-05-03 13:31:43,367 DEBG 'uwsgi' stdout output:
alerta-5d7db46658-jpdkm alerta     dictConfigClass(config).configure()
alerta-5d7db46658-jpdkm alerta   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/logging/config.py", line 546, in configure
alerta-5d7db46658-jpdkm alerta
alerta-5d7db46658-jpdkm alerta 2020-05-03 13:31:43,367 DEBG 'uwsgi' stdout output:
alerta-5d7db46658-jpdkm alerta     'formatter %r' % name) from e
alerta-5d7db46658-jpdkm alerta ValueError: Unable to configure formatter 'default'
alerta-5d7db46658-jpdkm alerta
alerta-5d7db46658-jpdkm alerta 2020-05-03 13:31:43,367 DEBG 'uwsgi' stdout output:
alerta-5d7db46658-jpdkm alerta unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='/api') (callable not found or import error)
alerta-5d7db46658-jpdkm alerta *** no app loaded. going in full dynamic mode ***
alerta-5d7db46658-jpdkm alerta *** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
alerta-5d7db46658-jpdkm alerta spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 11)
alerta-5d7db46658-jpdkm alerta
alerta-5d7db46658-jpdkm alerta 2020-05-03 13:31:43,369 DEBG 'uwsgi' stdout output:
alerta-5d7db46658-jpdkm alerta spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 20, cores: 1)
alerta-5d7db46658-jpdkm alerta
alerta-5d7db46658-jpdkm alerta 2020-05-03 13:31:43,369 DEBG 'uwsgi' stdout output:
alerta-5d7db46658-jpdkm alerta spawned uWSGI worker 2 (pid: 21, cores: 1)
alerta-5d7db46658-jpdkm alerta
alerta-5d7db46658-jpdkm alerta 2020-05-03 13:31:43,370 DEBG 'uwsgi' stdout output:
alerta-5d7db46658-jpdkm alerta
alerta-5d7db46658-jpdkm alerta 2020-05-03 13:31:43,367 DEBG 'uwsgi' stdout out
put:
alerta-5d7db46658-jpdkm alerta     'formatter %r' % name) from e
alerta-5d7db46658-jpdkm alerta ValueError: Unable to configure formatter 'defa
ult'
alerta-5d7db46658-jpdkm alerta
alerta-5d7db46658-jpdkm alerta 2020-05-03 13:31:43,367 DEBG 'uwsgi' stdout out
put:
alerta-5d7db46658-jpdkm alerta unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='/api') (calla
ble not found or import error)
alerta-5d7db46658-jpdkm alerta *** no app loaded. going in full dynamic mode *
**
```

This microservice uses a connection string that when trying to leverage to connect from the api pod to the db, I am getting the following error:

```
alerta@alerta-758bc87dcf-4r9bz:/$ psql postgresql://alerta:changeme@alerta-postgresql:5432/monitoring
psql: server closed the connection unexpectedly
    This probably means the server terminated abnormally
    before or while processing the request.
```

On any connection attempt, the following appears in `postgres` logs

```
alerta-postgresql-0 alerta-postgresql 2020-05-03 15:02:46.787 GMT [1274] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
```

Any suggestions?

**edit**: `postgres` logs during startup

```
alerta-postgresql-0 alerta-postgresql 2020-05-03 14:47:47.444 GMT [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
alerta-postgresql-0 alerta-postgresql 2020-05-03 14:47:47.444 GMT [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
```

Comment: I have the same question.  be nice to know what is triggering the error  :-)

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: Are you using nginx? I also have this problem, with a docker-based django / nginx-proxy / postgres setup. I get intermittent 502's. Here's what I found: https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/issues/2347#issuecomment-670797131

Comment: I just had similar issues trying to proxy TCP traffic using `ingress-nginx` to a `postgres` database installed using the `bitnami/postgresql` charts in a digitalocean cluster [had to Disable the Load Balancers proxy protocol settings for the connections to go through](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64044959/1423507).