# Unable to login to Postgres inside Kubernetes cluster from the outside

Tags: postgresql, docker, kubernetes, digital-ocean

I want to simply login to a postgres db from outside my K8 cluster. I'm created the following config:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
    name: postgres 
spec:
    replicas: 1
    selector: 
        matchLabels:
            app: postgres 
    template:
        metadata:
            labels:
                app: postgres 
        spec:
            volumes:
                - name: postgres-storage
                  persistentVolumeClaim: 
                    claimName: database-persistent-volume-claim
            containers:
                - name: postgres 
                  image: postgres
                  volumeMounts:
                    - name: postgres-storage
                      mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data
                      subPath: postgres
                  env:
                    - name: POSTGRES_USER
                      value: postgres
                    - name: POSTGRES_PORT
                      value: '5432'
                    - name: POSTGRES_DB
                      value: postgres
                    - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
                      value: password
                    - name: POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD
                      value: trust
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
    name: postgres-srv
spec:
    selector:
        app: postgres
    type: NodePort
    ports:
        - name: postgres
          protocol: TCP
          port: 5432
          targetPort: 5432
```

Config Map:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: tcp-services
  namespace: ingress-nginx
data:
  5432: "default/postgres-srv:5432"
```

I've checked `kubectl get services` and attempted to use the endpoint and the cluster-ip. Neith of these worked.

`psql "postgresql://postgres:password@[ip]:5432/postgres"`

The pod is running and the logs say everything is ready. Anything I'm missing here? I'm running the cluster in digital ocean.

edit:

I want to be able to access the DB from my host. (sub.domain.com) I've bounced the deployments and still can't get in. The only config I've targeted is what is shown above. I do have an A record for my domain and can access my other exposed pods via my ingress nginx service

Comment: Unless you have an ingress for the `postgres` service you should probably look into `port-forwarding` to forward traffic to services running inside the cluster i.e.: `kubectl port-forward postgresql-0 5432:5432` then connect using the local port i.e.: `psql "postgresql://postgres:password@localhost:5432/postgres"`.

Comment: Isn't ingress for HTTP traffic while postgres runs over TCP? I got this working by grabbing the node port and then using the IP of the VM IP instead of the service/node ip in the cluster.

Comment: You can [expose TCP and UDP services](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/exposing-tcp-udp-services/). Isn't an `Ingress` object (not supported) but using `ConfigMap`'s.

Comment: I'm interested in this idea as I'd prefer to use my host instead of a dynamic IP and some strange port. Any chance you could materialize this in an answer? I'm struggling to create the config map in place of what I'd typically do in my ingress controller

Comment: @masseyb I added config map, but cannot connect still using my domain name. Anything I'd be missing?

Comment: If you're running in the cloud (i.e. EKS or GKE) you'll probably need to open firewall ports to allow traffic the connections.

Comment: Added an answer and I'll correct myself whereas in GKE you don't need a firewall rule rather the traffic is allowed once the `ingress-nginx` service is modified to include the proxied port (e.g. updates existing firewall rules).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222029/discussion-between-masseyb-and-ryan).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can [expose TCP and UDP services](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/exposing-tcp-udp-services/) with `ingress-nginx` configuration.

For example using [GKE](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine) with [`ingress-nginx`](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/), [nfs-server-provisioner](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/nfs-server-provisioner) and the [`bitnami/postgresql`](https://bitnami.com/stack/postgresql/helm) [`helm`](https://helm.sh/) charts:

```sh
kubectl create secret generic -n default postgresql \
    --from-literal=postgresql-password=$(openssl rand -base64 32) \
    --from-literal=postgresql-replication-password=$(openssl rand -base64 32)
helm repo add bitnami https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami
helm install -n default postgres bitnami/postgresql \
    --set global.storageClass=nfs-client \
    --set existingSecret=postgresql
```

Patch the `ingress-nginx` `tcp-services` [`ConfigMap`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/configmap/):

```
kubectl patch cm -n ingress-nginx tcp-services -p '{"data": {"5432": "default/postgres-postgresql:5432"}}'
```

Update the controllers `Service` for the proxied port (i.e. `kubectl edit svc -n ingress-nginx ingress-nginx`):

```yaml
  - name: postgres
    port: 5432
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 5432
```

**Note**: you may have to update the existing `ingress-nginx` controller deployments `args` (i.e. `kubectl edit deployments.apps -n ingress-nginx nginx-ingress-controller`) to include `--tcp-services-configmap=ingress-nginx/tcp-services` and bounce the `ingress-nginx` controller if you edit the deployment spec (i.e. `kubectl scale deployment -n ingress-nginx --replicas=0 && kubectl scale deployment -n ingress-nginx --replicas=3`).

Test the connection:

```sh
export PGPASSWORD=$(kubectl get secrets -n default postgresql -o jsonpath={.data.postgresql-password} |base64 -d)
docker run --rm -it \
    -e PGPASSWORD=${PGPASSWORD} \
    --entrypoint psql \
    --network host \
    postgres:13-alpine -U postgres -d postgres -h example.com
```

[image: Connection to remote PostgreSQL database using dns resolution and ingress-nginx proxied traffic]

**Note**: I manually created an `A` record in [Google Cloud DNS](https://cloud.google.com/dns) to resolve the hostname to the clusters external IP.

**Update**: in addition to creating the `ingress-nginx` config, installing the `bitnami/postgresql` chart etc. it was necessary to Disable "Proxy Protocol" on the Load Balancer to get the connections working for a deployment in DigitalOcean (`postgres` will `LOG:  invalid length of startup packet` otherwise):

[image: Digital Ocean postgres connection through public load balancer]

Comment: thanks for the response! I'm running DigitalOcean manager k8 cluster and still seem to be having issues here.  Updating my original post if you happen to have any insight

Comment: Very detailed response and helpful, thanks @masseyb!